# iTunes 10.7 on Catalina

Tags: itunes, catalina

Is it possible to install iTunes 10.7 in Catalina? It can be done in High Sierra by removing iTunes 12.8 from apps and running the 10.7 installer.

Comment: There's an app called Retroactive that will enable iTunes installation, but idk whether it will enable iTunes 10 - see https://www.simplehelp.net/2019/10/30/how-to-install-itunes-in-macos-catalina/ What is it about iTunes 10 that you specifically need?

Comment: Thank you. It seems 10.7 is possible.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes 10.7 is nearly 10 years old, and designed to work with OSes of a similar vintage. https://support.apple.com/kb/SP590

It is very unlikely that it would work with Catalina. Apple's bundled apps heavily rely on OS frameworks, libraries and functions, and the OS has changed dramatically since then.

Catalina saw the 'break-up' of iTunes into Music, TV, and other apps, with the Finder taking over syncing of iPhones, etc.

It would be much better if you work out what it is that you ***need*** that in is this app, and see if there is another way to produce that functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the functionality needed would require me to get an app build from scratch. Alternate pay a developer to try to adjust the framecode to work on Catalina, although I can imagine it would be a huge job.

Comment: What is the functionality? Are you sure it is absent, even if in a different form?

Comment: Its not in absent so to speak, but it works differently, and I prefer the old version. Thanks for your very clear answer though!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it can bo done through the Retroactive app. At least based on the last part of this article.

https://forums.appleinsider.com/discussion/213510#first-reply